# ¿Como eliminar en dos tablas?

Tags: mysql, sql

estoy desarrollando un sistema de gestión de activos fijos y tengo dos tablas donde se dan de bajas activos adquiridos, una tablas es `bajasaf` y la otra es `distribdebajas`. En `bajasaf` se guarda la información como el `id_baja, fecha_baja, cantidad_baja` y en la tabla `distribdebajas` se guarda el `id_baja, id_adquisicion, cantidad_rebajada y saldo_restante`, el `saldo_restante` se calcula para una misma adquisición y en `distribdebajas` puede haber varias bajas con distintos saldos, hasta llega a cero, como se muestra en la imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito que al eliminar una baja, por ejemplo esta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

también me elimine las filas con saldo menores a la fila que se elimino en este caso de la foto, seria el con el saldo 2 y 0 y me dejaría solo la fila con saldo 12.

OJO: La eliminación yo la hago desde la tabla bajas y es en forma de `CASCADE`, para que me elimine la fila con el mismo `id_baja` en `distribdebajas`, pero también necesito que elimine las filas como en el ejemplo explicado.

Comment: @Lorthas me parece, voy a probar, muchas gracias.

Comment: Ya has ensayado TRIGGER (Desencadenantes)?

Comment: De todas formas tampoco que me queda muy clara la relacion entre esas dos tablas.
id_baja es la clave primaria en bajasaf y id_adquisicion es la clave foranea en distribdebajas?

Answer (score 0):

Podrias usar una subconsulta en base al ID de baja que tomas como referencia. No es una manera muy elegante pero funciona.

Te dejo el ejemplo

```
DELETE FROM
    prueba
WHERE
    id_baja IN (select id_baja from prueba WHERE saldo_adqui <= (select saldo_adqui from prueba where id_baja = 101))
    AND id_activo = (select id_activo from prueba where id_baja = 101)
```

Tambien podrias usar un procedimiento almacenado o bien como lo menciona Weimar un Trigger.